# Not reading utf-8 marks

Tags: android, utf-8, textview, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have a .txt file on my sdcard with utf-8 marks e.g.:

"Jak przetrwa**ć** w**ś**r**ó**d czarnych dziur"

And this is how I try to read them from this file:

```
public static void readBooksFromTxtFile(Context context, String filePath, ArrayList<SingleBook> books) {
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String title = line;
            String author = in.readLine();
            String pages = in.readLine();
            String date = in.readLine();

            // just for debugging
            System.out.println(title);

            books.add(new SingleBook(title, author, pages, date));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error during reading file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't read the file correctly:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is here:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"));
```

Instead it should be

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath));
```

This should read it correctly. If not, you can just use RandomAccessFile:

```
public static void readBooksFromTxtFile(Context context, String filePath, ArrayList<SingleBook> books) {
RandomAccessFile in;
try {
    in = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filePath), "r");
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readUTF8()) != null) {
        String title = line;
        String author = in.readUTF8();
        String pages = in.readUTF8();
        String date = in.readUTF8();

        // just for debugging
        System.out.println(title);

        books.add(new SingleBook(title, author, pages, date));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error during reading file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
}
```